# How to use Angular router outlet inside a component which itself is served via primary router outlet?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to make a `router-outlet` work inside `DashboardComponent` which itself is served via `router-outler` present in `app.component.html`.

The flow that I am trying to achieve goes like this:

- After user logins, user is redirected to `/dashboard` which will load `DashboardComponent`.
- `DashboardComponent` contains `mat-sidenav-container` with `mat-sidenav` links and a `div` container, inside which I have to serve different components - `AComponent`, `BComponent`, `CComponent` depending on the link clicked in `mat-sidenav`.

That is, path `localhost:4200/dashboard/componentA` should show `AComponent` in `DashboardComponent` 's div container and so on.

- path `/dashboard` should redirect to `/dashboard/componentA`

I am having hard time trying to figure out how to show the components inside `DashboardComponent` using `router-outlet`.

Is this possible? Is there any better way to do this?

[Working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qvacwn/)

```js
**app.routing.ts**

    import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
    import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
    
    import { AComponent } from './a/a.component';
    import { BComponent } from './b/b.component';
    import { CComponent } from './c/c.component';
    
    export const appRoutes: Routes = [
        { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
        { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, outlet: 'dashboard',
        children: [
            { path: '', component:  AComponent },
            { path: 'componentA', component:  AComponent },
            { path: 'componentB', component: BComponent },
            { path: 'componentC', component: CComponent }
           
          ]},
    
        // otherwise redirect to home
       //  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
    ];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you have works, with a few modifications.

Firstly, you don't need to assign a name to your router-outlet inside dashboard component. Named outlets have a different use case, you can read about them [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#displaying-multiple-routes-in-named-outlets):

Here are the modifications you need to make

1. Remove the outlet property from the dashboard route in app.routing.ts
2. Remove the name directive from the router-outlet in dashboard.component.html
3. Remove the 'dashboard/' from the [routerLink] in the a tags dashboard.component.html. Since these routes are children of the currently activated route, they their paths will automatically be appended after dashboard.

```js
//dashboard.component.html
<mat-sidenav #sidenav align="start" position="start" mode="side"  opened="true" class="example-sidenav  side-nav-style">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a [routerLink]="['componentA']">componentA</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a [routerLink]="['componentB']">componentB</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a [routerLink]="['componentC']">componentC</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</mat-sidenav>
<div class="content">
  <p>dashboard works!</p>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>          
</div>
         
//app.routing.ts
children: [
  // { path: '', component:  AComponent },
  { path: 'componentA', component:  AComponent },
  { path: 'componentB', component: BComponent },
  { path: 'componentC', component: CComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'componentA', pathMatch: 'full'}
]},
```

Additionally, notice I commented the first line in the children array and replaced it with a new one at the end. Using this approach, whenever the path is empty, it will automatically redirect to componentA and change the route as well, rather than just show componentA on an empty path.

[Updated code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ah4f2u)

Comment: In the very same scenario, what if I need to show the url as `/componentA` instead of `/dashboard/componentA` and also as `/componentB` instead of `/dashboard/componentB` ?

Comment: Your code on StackBlitz gives me an error when loading one of the letter components: `Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'componentA'`

Answer (score 2):

You basically have two routes pointing out to the same component.

```
{ path: '', component: DashboardComponent },
{ path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, }
```

You should use redirect to achieve your desired behavior.
And in your dashboard.html - links to child components are absolute - it breaks the navigation anyway in your case - consider to use relative links. You don't need to specify a name of route outlet in this case as well - will work out of the box with proper routing setup.
Once i fixed all of the above - navigation started to work.

See code samples below:

**app.routing.ts**

```
 export const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: '', pathMatch: "full", redirectTo: 'dashboard' },
{
   path: 'dashboard', 
    component: DashboardComponent ,
    children: [
    { path: 'componentA', component:  AComponent },
    { path: 'componentB', component: BComponent },
    { path: 'componentC', component: CComponent }

  ]},
```

];

**dashboard.component.html**

```
<mat-sidenav #sidenav align="start" position="start" mode="side"  opened="true" class="example-sidenav  side-nav-style">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a [routerLink]="['./componentA']">componentA</a>
    </li>
     <li>
      <a [routerLink]="['./componentB']">componentB</a>
    </li>
     <li>
      <a [routerLink]="['./componentC']">componentC</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</mat-sidenav>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made some modifications to your routing file and the dashboard component file.

First you don't need to use named routes.
Secondly children routes take their parents initial path so no need to provide them again and you can directly specify the child route name in router link.

you can check the working code here

[working code](https://angular-jhr51r.stackblitz.io/dashboard/componentC)

hope this solves your issue.

Comment: This solves the problem but please share the edit url of your working code so that I can see the code

Comment: just realised that only one answer can be marked as answer. oops

Comment: No issues. Until it solves your problem you can accept any solution which best fits your problem description.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change your routing file.

First off you need to redirect `path: ''` to `dashboard`:

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'  },
```

And blank route of children should redirect to componentA:

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'componentA', pathMatch: 'full' },
```

So basically your updated routes look like:

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'  },

    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'componentA', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'componentA', component:  AComponent },
        { path: 'componentB', component: BComponent },
        { path: 'componentC', component: CComponent }

    ]},

    // otherwise redirect to home
    // { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

I have also forked and created [working demo](https://angular-qznj2s.stackblitz.io/dashboard/componentB) from your demo.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone like me land on this issue and still couldn't resolve it, I found my solution by reading the Angular tutorial : https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh#child-routing-component

Be very careful about the module imports. The child routing module must be imported before the general app routing module. Also make sure the module of your parent component is not imported in the module where you have your general app routing module.
These will change in which router-outlet the child page will appear.